# EntityFramework and SignalR - broadcasting updates to database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, signalr

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I'm kind of new to .NET.

I've got a database that I want to monitor using SignalR. Whenever a new record satisfying certain parameters gets pushed into the DB, I want to broadcast that to my client.

How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Tons of programming. Start with SignalR not being able to monitor a database. Go on with most databases not really being monitorable. Way too broad - we answer concrete questions, we do not do complete architectures here.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR
This works between the Server and the Client its not designed to monitor a database, but it can be used to call update functions that reside within the client software when the server has information that it wants to pass on to the connected clients.

Entity Framework
You could write a MyDatabaseContext that inherits from DbContext
Then you could override all methods like SaveChanges, SaveChangesAsync and add your own code to create an "audit" methods that allows you to capture what the code is about update.

```
public MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IAuditDatabaseChange _auditDatabaseChange;

    static CommonDatabaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CommonDatabaseContext>(null);
    }

    public CommonDatabaseContext() {
        _runningMigrations = true;
    }

    public CommonDatabaseContext(IAuditDatabaseChange auditService)
    {
        _auditDatabaseChangeService = auditService;
        _runningMigrations = false;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        if (!_runningMigrations)
        {
            await _auditDatabaseChange.SaveAudit(this);
        }
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        if (!_runningMigrations)
        {
            Task.Run(() => _auditDatabaseChange.SaveAudit(this)).Wait();
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Of course this is just an idea of how it could be achieved you'll have to define all the services, provide and configure a Dependency Injection Framework of your choice, add in all the missing stuff from the Context such as initialization and the required EF mappings etc....

It may point you in the right direction.